# Datedif (total days) getting wrong answer

Tags: excel, function

Issues with total days calculation as shown below snapshot orange colour:
[image]

Comment: In 5th row you divide 14 years ant 1 month by 2 and get 7 (half) years but still 1 full month. Also DATEDIF arguments are dates, passing 0 and G6=3579 means you are calculating difference between 1909 10 18 and 1900 01 00 (non existing date). Not much makes sense here

Comment: @user11222393 Except for the error in Excel's calendar (including `29-Feb-1900`) it does kind of make sense as the end_date will equate to a date that is the same duration from start_date as would be the case. `DATEDIF` is inherently inaccurate anyway (with the `MD` parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Years and Months do not all contain the same number of days, `DATEDIF` can frequently give incorrect answers because of assumptions it makes in regard to the number of days in a month. As an example, consider:

```
=DATEDIF("31-jan-2023","1-mar-2023","md") => -2
```

For your particular calculations could use `0` for `start_date` and `%Total Days` for `end_date`,

But to correct the inherent flaw in `DATEDIF` you will need to write a routine that handles the difference in lengths of months differently. Or use it and accept that it may be inaccurate if the last month has fewer days than the first month.

Or, you could just define a year as having 360 days and a month as having 30 days as is done in some financial calculations.

Here is an example using `DATEDIF` which will be as accurate as it can be given the variability in the length of a month and year

[image]

Comment: How do I get total of value of year (H2+H3), month (I2+I3) and days((J2+J3) of both (H2+H3) this was my query.

Comment: @MadhuPrakash Huh? Your question is not clear. Why can't you just add them?

Comment: If I add 2 months like - 4 + 10 will come 14 in Months column instead of 1 in Year column and 2 in Months column.

Comment: @MadhuPrakash Just use one of the formulas (I would recommend the `0` based formula) but reference the total of the % Total column instead of the individual date

Comment: I have tried that, that formula for individual dates works, but for total days does not works. I just need in J5, if total 32 days should  be shown only 2 dyas and the other 30 days to move column I5 as 1

Comment: @MadhuPrakash Works on your example as you can see from my screenshot.